# How to attach and mount an EFS to my EC2 instance using AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

I'd like to automatically mount an `EFS` to my `EC2 instance` using AWS CDK.

I created the file system:

```py
        self.file_system = efs.FileSystem(
            scope=self,
            id="Efs",
            vpc=self.vpc,
            file_system_name="EFS",
            removal_policy=RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
        )
```

and the Ec2 instance:

```py
        self.ec2_instance = ec2.Instance(
            scope=self,
            id="ec2Instance",
            instance_name="my_ec2_instance",
            instance_type=ec2.InstanceType.of(
                instance_class=ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE2,
                instance_size=ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO,
            ),
            machine_image=ec2.AmazonLinuxImage(
                generation=ec2.AmazonLinuxGeneration.AMAZON_LINUX_2
            ),
            vpc=self.vpc,
            vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC),
            key_name="ec2-key-pair",
            security_group=ec2_security_group,
        )
```

Now what do I need to do to get them attached? I see many examples of doing this on the console, but so far I haven't found a way to do it in AWS CDK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just call connect on your created EFS after you created both EFS and EC2:

```
file_system.connections.allow_default_port_from(instance)
```

In your case:

```
self.file_system.connections.allow_default_port_from(self.ec2_instance)
```

Here is the documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_efs/README.html#connecting

If you need to mount it during launch, you can execute code via the user data of ec2:

```
file_system.connections.allow_default_port_from(instance)

instance.user_data.add_commands("yum check-update -y", "yum upgrade -y", "yum install -y amazon-efs-utils", "yum install -y nfs-utils", "file_system_id_1=" + file_system.file_system_id, "efs_mount_point_1=/mnt/efs/fs1", "mkdir -p "${efs_mount_point_1}"", "test -f "/sbin/mount.efs" && echo "${file_system_id_1}:/ ${efs_mount_point_1} efs defaults,_netdev" >> /etc/fstab || " + "echo "${file_system_id_1}.efs." + Stack.of(self).region + ".amazonaws.com:/ ${efs_mount_point_1} nfs4 nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport,_netdev 0 0" >> /etc/fstab", "mount -a -t efs,nfs4 defaults")
```

Documentaion pieces here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_efs/README.html#mounting-the-file-system-using-user-data

Comment: Thanks so much for the links. I'm surprised my search didn't turn them up - It was exactly what I needed and everything is hooked up now. I needed to be a bit clever with the apostrophes in Python CDK. Here is a gist: https://gist.github.com/wcheek/59064888c3552cf822c05cb5dd941e27